# Bibliography for IEEEtranTIE

Tags: bibliographies

I am writing the below lines for bibliography in the main file

```
\bibliographystyle{Bibliography/IEEEtranTIE}
\bibliography{ref1.bib}
```

But, I am getting only a heading 'REFERENCES'in the pdf. The contents of references are not being displayed. How should I resolve the problem?

Comment: Yes, I have cited 2 of them. In text citiations are showing a ? instead of the number

Comment: I am using a TexStudio .tex file with .bib file.

Comment: I have understood it. Following code lines are to be written forTIE 
                                       
           \bibliographystyle{Bibliography/IEEEtranTIE}
           \bibliography{Bibliography/IEEEabrv,Bibliography/ref1}\